# FPDF error: Some data has already been output - PHP script

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

Hi guys I'm trying to modify a pdf file and store it in my server, but i keep getting this error : `FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file` and i can't manage to figure the cause of it.

Here is the PHP script:

```
<?php
ob_start();
include_once '../db_connect.php';

$JOUR = date('d');
$MOIS = date('m');
$ANNEE = date('Y');
$TIME = date("h:i:s");
$date = $ANNEE . "-" . $MOIS . "-" . $JOUR . " " . $TIME;

// titre rapport
$rapFR = $_POST['rapportFR'];
$rapUK = $_POST['rapportUK'];
$categ = $_POST['categ'];
$rapportFR = str_replace("/", "-", $rapFR);
$rapportUK = str_replace("/", "-", $rapUK);

$cherche = array('é', 'è', 'ê', 'ç', 'à', 'â', 'û', 'ù', '/');
$remplace = array('e', 'e', 'e', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'u', 'u', '-');

//noms pour les fichiers upload
$uploadFR = str_replace($cherche, $remplace, $rapFR);
$uploadUK = str_replace($cherche, $remplace, $rapUK);
//echo $uploadFR;

//message optionnel
$messageAdditionel = $_POST['elm1'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO rapport(categorie,date,titreUK,titreFR,nomfichier)  VALUES ('$categ', '$date', '$rapportUK', '$rapportFR', '$rapportFR');";
$req = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die('Erreur SQL !<br/>' . $sql . '<br/>' . mysqli_error($mysqli));

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM rapport ORDER BY idr DESC;";
$req2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql2) or die('Erreur SQL !<br/>' . $sql2 .    '<br/>' . mysqli_error($mysqli));
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($req2);
$idr = $data['idr'];
$sqlIdRap = "SELECT * FROM rapport ORDER BY idr DESC LIMIT 1;";
$reqIdRap = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlIdRap) or die('Erreur SQL !<br/>' .    $sqlIdRap . '<br/>' . mysqli_error($mysqli));
if ($dataIdRap = mysqli_fetch_array($reqIdRap)) {
$idRapport = $data['idr'];
}

$dirFR = '../articles/FR/' . $idRapport . '-' . $uploadFR;
$dirUK = '../articles/UK/' . $idRapport . '-' . $uploadUK . '/';

if ($dataIdRap = mysqli_fetch_array($reqIdRap)) {
$idRapport = $data['idr'];
}

$dirFR = '../articles/FR/' . $idRapport . '-' . $uploadFR;
$dirUK = '../articles/UK/' . $idRapport . '-' . $uploadUK . '/';


$oldmask = umask(0);
if (!file_exists($dirFR)) {
mkdir($dirFR, 777, true);
}
if (!file_exists($dirUK)) {
mkdir($dirUK, 777, true);
}
umask($oldmask);
$count = 0;

setlocale(LC_TIME, 'en_US.UTF-8', 'en');
$dateUK = strftime('%A %d %B %Y');
$dateUK = mb_convert_encoding($dateUK, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR.utf8', 'fra');
$dateFR = strftime('%A %d %B %Y');
$dateFR = mb_convert_encoding($dateFR, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');

$monRapportFR = $dirFR . "/$uploadFR.php"; // or .php 
//recuperation du fichier PDF
$pdfFR = $_FILES['rapportFR']['name'];

$fh = fopen($monRapportFR, 'w'); // or die("error");  
$corpsFR = "$entete";




$corpsFR .= "</head><body>";

$extention = pathinfo($pdfFR, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['rapportFR']['tmp_name'], $dirFR . "/" . $pdfFR)) {

}
$dirFinal = $dirFR . $pdfFR;
// if($option_impression==true){
$corpsFR .= "<embed src='$pdfFR' style='float:left;width:100%;height:100%'>";
// }
$corpsFR .= "</body> </html>";
fwrite($fh, $corpsFR);

$monRapportUK = $dirUK . "/$uploadUK.php"; // or .php 
//recuperation du fichier PDF
$pdfUK = $_FILES['rapportUK']['name'];
//echo $pdfUK;

$fh = fopen($monRapportUK, 'w'); // or die("error");  
$corpsUK = "$entete";




$corpsUK .= "</head><body>";

$extention = pathinfo($pdfUK, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['rapportUK']['tmp_name'], $dirUK . "/" . $pdfUK)) {

}
$dirFinal = $dirUK . $pdfUK;
// if($option_impression==true){
$corpsUK .= "<embed src='$pdfUK' style='float:left;width:100%;height:100%'>";
// }
$corpsUK .= "</body> </html>";
fwrite($fh, $corpsUK);

require_once '../swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';

$sql4 = "SELECT * FROM appartenir, groupe, contact WHERE groupe.idg = appartenir.idg AND appartenir.idc = contact.idc AND appartenir.idg = $categ AND isDeleted = 0 ;";
$req4 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql4) or die('Erreur SQL !<br/>' . $sql4 . '<br/>' . mysqli_error($mysqli));

//indicateurs listes fr/uk
$nbrFR = 0;
$nbrUK = 0;

$ajoutSQL = "";

//liste des contacts fr/uk
$destinataireFR = array();
$destinataireUK = array();


while ($data4 = mysqli_fetch_array($req4)) {
    $idc = $data4['idc'];
    $emailC = $data4['mail'];
    $cle = $idr . $idc . bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8));
    $langue = $data4['langue'];

//fin du lien de rapport
    $data = array('idr' => $idr,
    'cle' => $cle);
    $url = "?" . http_build_query($data);

    $lienFR = "127.0.0.1/newsletter/articles/FR/" . $idRapport ."-". $uploadFR . "/" . $uploadFR . ".php" . $url;
    $lienUK = "127.0.0.1/newsletter/articles/UK/" . $idRapport ."-". $uploadUK . "/" . $uploadUK . ".php" . $url;

    if($langue=="FR"){
      $destinataireFR[$nbrFR] = array(
        "mail" => $emailC,
        "lien" => $lienFR
    );
    $nbrFR++;
}else{
      $destinataireUK[$nbrUK] = array(
        "mail" => $emailC,
        "lien" => $lienUK
    );
    $nbrUK++;
}
$ajoutSQL = $ajoutSQL ."('$cle',$idr,$idc),";
///// ajouter message additionel //////
$messageAdditionel;
}
//suppression de la derniere virgule
$ajoutSQL = rtrim($ajoutSQL,",");

//Ajout cle dans Code
$sql5 = "INSERT INTO code(cle,idr,idc) VALUES $ajoutSQL;";
$req5 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql5) or die('Erreur SQL !<br/>' . $sql5 .   '<br/>' . mysqli_error($mysqli));

// SMTP
require '../smtp/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->IsSMTP();

//paramètres et contenu du mail
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      
$mail->Username = "test";
$mail->Password= "test";
$mail->Port       = 587;                   
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";   
$mail->From = "test@test.fr";
$mail->IsHTML(true);
require_once('../fpdf17/fpdf.php');
require_once('../FPDI/fpdi.php');
$pdf = new FPDI();

foreach($destinataireFR as $destinataireFR){ 
$mail->Body = "<p style='font-family:Calibri'>Bonjour,<br/><br/><a href='$destinataireFR[lien]' style='font-size:1.1em'>Cliquez ici</a> pour ouvrir le fichier <b>$rapportFR</b>.<br/><br/>Cordialement,<br/><br/><b style='color:#4271BE'>L'Equipe Horizon Soft Commodities</b><br/>01.49.89.46.16<br/><a href='mailto:analyse@horizon-sc.fr'>analyse@horizon-sc.fr</a><br/><br/><br/><p style='font-size:0.8em'>Si vous souhaitez vous d&eacute;sinscrire et ne plus recevoir ces messages, <a href='mailto:analyse@horizon-sc.fr &subject=Desinscription'>cliquez ici</a>.</p><br/>$messageAdditionel</p>";
$mail->Subject = "$rapportFR";
$mail->AddAddress("$destinataireFR[mail]");
    if($categ == 27)
    {

        // add a page
        $pdf->AddPage();
        // set the source file
        $pdf->setSourceFile($dirFR . "/" . $pdfFR);
        // import page 1
        $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
        // use the imported page and place it at point 0,0 with a width of 300 mm(pour un centrage comme reel)
        $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 300);
        $pdf->SetXY(70, 70);
        $pdf->Write(0, "test");
        $pdf->SetXY(100, 80);
        $pdf->Write(0, "test");  
    }
if ($mail->Send()){
    // echo "success<br/>"; 
}else{
    // echo "fail : ". $mail->ErrorInfo . "<br/>";
}
$mail->ClearAddresses();
}
$pdf->Output();
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

`db_connect.php`

```
<?php
include_once 'sql-config.php'; // file contening db credentials
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
$mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

//message d'erreur en cas d'échec
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Echec lors de la connexion à MySQL : (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

Someone knows where does this come from ?

Comment: Can we see the full PHP script. The issue seems to be the $pdf->output() call at the end. FPDF can't sent output to the browser as something has already been sent. It could be something as simple as a blank line before your opening <?php tag.

Comment: Well actually my script is more that 300 lines long, should I still post it ? There is no blank line before the <?php tag thought, neither at the end

Comment: Have a look through it for anything that might be outputting data, an echo command, a blank line before a <?php tag.

Comment: Yep thats what I did, I commented every echo commands but it doesn't seem to resolve the problem :/

Comment: Have you also checked inside your included files.

Comment: i don't think so but which file do you mean ? ?

Comment: Can we see the contents of db_connect.php (without any db credentials)

Comment: @SheppardDigital Yeah sure, i just added the script at the end

Comment: I guess you save your file in UTF-8? If so, ensure that you do a resave and force [UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having had another look at your script, it looks like you are potentially creating multiple PDF files but only outputting the last one.

I think the includes and the FPDF instantiation should be outside of the foreach like this;

```
require_once('../fpdf17/fpdf.php');
require_once('../FPDI/fpdi.php');

$pdf = new FPDI();

foreach($destinataireFR as $destinataireFR) { 
    $mail->Body = "<p style='font-family:Calibri'>Bonjour,<br/><br/><a href='$destinataireFR[lien]' style='font-size:1.1em'>Cliquez ici</a> pour ouvrir le fichier <b>$rapportFR</b>.<br/><br/>Cordialement,<br/><br/><b style='color:#4271BE'>L'Equipe Horizon Soft Commodities</b><br/>01.49.89.46.16<br/><a href='mailto:analyse@horizon-sc.fr'>analyse@horizon-sc.fr</a><br/><br/><br/><p style='font-size:0.8em'>Si vous souhaitez vous d&eacute;sinscrire et ne plus recevoir ces messages, <a href='mailto:analyse@horizon-sc.fr &subject=Desinscription'>cliquez ici</a>.</p><br/>$messageAdditionel</p>";
    $mail->Subject = "$rapportFR";
    $mail->AddAddress("$destinataireFR[mail]");
    if($categ == 27)
    {
        // add a page
        $pdf->AddPage();
        // set the source file
        $pdf->setSourceFile($dirFR . "/" . $pdfFR);
        // import page 1
        $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
        // use the imported page and place it at point 0,0 with a width of 300 mm(pour un centrage comme reel)
        $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 300);
        $pdf->SetXY(70, 70);
        $pdf->Write(0, "test");
        $pdf->SetXY(100, 80);
        $pdf->Write(0, "test");  
    }
if ($mail->Send()){
    // echo "success<br/>"; 
}else{
    // echo "fail : ". $mail->ErrorInfo . "<br/>";
}
$mail->ClearAddresses();
}
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Oh you're right it shoudln't be in the foreach ! Just moved it but the problem is still there..

Comment: Sadly without seeing all of the code it's difficult to tell what the problem is, it certainly doesn't look to be with the code you've pasted.

Comment: Yeah I understand, well here is the full script then, sorry if it's a bit long :p

Answer (score 0):

Add these functions right after opening and closing php tags.

```
<?php 
ob_start();
// php code here
ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, but it doesn't seem to work here :(

Comment: where do you add ob_start(); ? can I see it in your code?

Comment: sure i just added the very beggining of the script !